# How to 'clone' select metabox options with a callback function?

Tags: metabox, callbacks

Here is my metabox

```
      array(
        'id'    => 'all_btns',
        'name'  => 'Button Select',
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'button'         => 'Button',
            'button_red'     => 'Button Red',
            'button_yellow'  => 'Button Yellow',

        ),             
        'callback' => 'metabox_clone_options',
      ),
```

I want to clone this **options** to another metabox array

Comment: Don't know if it's a good solution or not, but I created a helper function (let's say `get_button_styles()`) in functions.php file, which returns an array with style options. Than you can just call this function as many times as you want. `'options' => get_buttons_styles()`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, I was thinking about a solution for hours, it helped me a lot

Comment: Glad it helped you. I will add a comment as an answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a simple function in your functions.php file.

```
function get_button_styles(){
    return array(
        'button'         => 'Button',
        'button_red'     => 'Button Red',
        'button_yellow'  => 'Button Yellow',

    );
}
```

Use it to get button styles in different metabox fields

```
array(
    'id'    => 'all_btns',
    'name'  => 'Button Select',
    'type'  => 'select',
    'options' => get_button_styles(),             
    'callback' => 'metabox_clone_options',
),
```